# Entity Framework - Can't seem to load related entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm a bit of an EF newb and I'm using .net core and I just can't seem to load the related entities of an entity unless I do a full-fledged "from..in..join" linq statement.

My entities have Guid primary keys and I'm using SQL Server as a DB.

Let's look at one entity that I'm having trouble with.

```
[Table("User")]
public class User : AuditableEntity
{
  public Group CurrentlySelectedGroup { get; set; }
}

[Table("Group")]
public class Group : AuditableEntity
{      
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

A user can pick one group as their "selected" group. I ran the migration statement and sure enough it created exactly what I wanted on the DB - a brand new column called CurrentlySelectedGroupId that was a FK to the Group table's PK column.

So this looks great.

I then ran some code that added a valid Guid for a valid group into the table.

Now when I execute this line of code:

```
 var user = _dbContext.Users.Where(u => u.Id == userId).FirstOrDefault();
```

It returns my user perfectly, but all the related entities are null.
I've even tried things like .Include(), including 'virtual', but no luck.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to lazy load or eager load the navigation properties?

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but it's lazy loading if I specify virtual, and eager loading if I don't?

Comment: Use Include function after where

Comment: @viveknuna no luck - any other ideas?

Comment: What did you write?

Comment: @NullHypothesis You have to enable lazy loading in the configuration and as vivek has pointed out, it's only available in EF 2.1 or later.  Eager loaded properties can still be virtual.  Looks like from your answer, you are definitely using eager loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lazy loading is not enabled, this feature was included in EF Core 2.1. In your case [Explicit Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#explicit-loading) is happening so you need to explicitly load the related entities. So If you are using EF Core 2.1, you can just enable the [Lazy Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading) and use related entities without explicitly adding them.

Answer (score 1):

After much trial and error, it seems the following works:

```
  var user = _dbContext.Users.Single(u => u.Id == userId);
  _dbContext.Entry(user).Reference(u => u.CurrentlySelectedGroup).Load();
```

Any ideas why this would work yet not anything else?

Thanks

Comment: which EF Core version you have?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
public class User
{
  [ForeignKey("CurrentlySelectedGroupId")]
  public Group myGroup { get; set; }
}
```

=================

```
var user = _dbContext.Users.Where(u => u.Id == userId).Include(u => u.myGroup).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.